# String comparison passing through if statement when it shouldn't

Tags: grails, groovy

I'm comparing values of an excel sheet to record values returned from a database and one record is passing through the if statement when it should fail the if statement.

The if statement looks like this:

```
if (record.value.equals(cellVal) == false)

    {
        record.value = cellVal
        record.modifyUser = userId
        //dataService.updateManualEntry(record)
        println "UPDATING ${record.value.equals(cellVal)}"
        println "record value: ${record.value}"                                 
        updatedCount++
        }else{
            println "NOT UPDATING [ [ ${record.value.length()} ]  + [${cellVal.length()}]"

        }

            }
```

The println shows that the value of `println "UPDATING ${record.value.equals(cellVal)}"` evaluates to be true, in which case I don't understand why it is passing through the if statement. In addition the length of the string is 0.

Can I get a second pair of eyes and figure out why a true value would get through this if statement?

Comment: You're printing `UPDATING ${record.value.equals(cellVal)}` _after_ you've done `record.value = cellVal`. Print it out before you change it, and show us the specific strings it fails on. Also, surround the values you're printing with e.g. a ' so it's easier to see whitespace

Comment: What's the value of cellVal? What language is this? Sorry, tagged Java of course... but where are your semicolons? Js?

Comment: It's tagged grails, so I'd assume it's groovy (which runs on the jvm)

Answer (score 4):

Your printlns happen *after* you have changed the value to match.

Answer (score 3):

Here:

```
record.value = cellVal
```

You have set record.value to cellVal inside the `if` block. That's why the `println` returns true.

Answer (score 2):

```
(true == false) ⇒ false
```

Answer (score 2):

the println is showing true becoz of the 1st line in your if statement

> record.value = cellVal

try printing the same value before if statement.

Answer (score 0):

if ->record.value.equals(cellVal) give u false
u compare (false)==false, naturally false is always = false, hence it will pass through

2nd, look at ur code,

**record.value = cellVal**

record.modifyUser = userId

//dataService.updateManualEntry(record)

println "UPDATING ${**record.value.equals(cellVal)**}"

U assign record.value = cellVal before u do a print.
Of cuz it will print true.